# Openshift 4.2 - Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I tried to create a cluster in Openshift 4.2 (RHCOS) environment. I have own local DNS server and HA proxy server. I created 3 master and 2 worker nodes in VMware Environment as per the documentation. At the end of the new cluster creation I'm getting an error :

> Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is
>   not yet valid

Does anyone have an idea why am I getting this error?

Comment: Do you have NTP configured and time synced across all nodes ?

Comment: Do you complete the installation within 24 hours ? The Ignition config files that the installation program generates contain certificates that expire after 24 hours. You must complete your cluster installation and keep the cluster running for 24 hours in a non-degraded state to ensure that the first certificate rotation has finished. Refer [OpenShift Container Platform installation overview](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.2/architecture/architecture-installation.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes...I finished the installation within 24 hours..I am newbie for an openshift..It's really surprising me while working on it.I read the link you mentioned it and really helped me to understand the installation process..thank you so much @DaeinPark

Answer (score 4):

It's an ignition file problem.When we create a ignition file, we have to finish the installation with in 24 hours.Because the ignition files contains certificate and it will expires in 24 hours.

[image: RHCOS Documentation]

Comment: **yes**.. @mWatney

Answer (score 2):

You must delete all install folder. Not enough to delete inside of install folder. Because install folder contains hidden file and those files creates old ignition files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Saved me a bunch of hours troubleshooting. This was my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem.
But just regenerating ignition config files did not fix the problem.

To fix it I had to alto delete the auth/ subfolder & regenerate.